# Intellij IDEA, angular 2 HTML template auto formatting

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA, angular 2 HTML template auto formatting

I use Intellij IDEA for angular2 development. I have a component.html template in a separate file.
Auto formatting does not work in this html template file (Ctrl + Alt + L).
Idea shows me a lot of errors in the file.

First one is at first line:

```
<div id="content" *ngIf="company">
<div class="panel panel-default actionbar">
<div class="panel-body">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

> *ngIf="company"  - Unexpected tokens

Formatting is incorrect after that line.

It seems to me, that Idea did not recognize angular2 *ngIf directive.

If I replace '*ngIf'  with 'ngIf'  - auto formatting works correctly:

```
<div id="content" ngIf="company">
..<div class="panel panel-default actionbar">
....<div class="panel-body">

....</div>
..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything works fine here. What is the code that doesn't format correctly? What is your question?

Comment: I’ve added samples of auto format results

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe you have an outdated IntelliJ version.

Comment: ultimate 2016.3.4. win10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. inline templates formatting is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-18307](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18307)
2. `*ngIf` is correctly recognized to me. make sure that Angular2 support is enabled for your project (**AngularJS** plugin installed, @angular node_modules are there)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Finally I’ve made a clean install of Intellij Idea without importing of previous settings  and it works fine now (I’m using external template file).  Obviously, I have some plugins corrupted. Reinstall with import previous settings did not solve the problem.  I mark this question as answered.